# How can I change the default behaviour of an input type date, that allow us typing 6 digits in year instead of 4 digits? Only using firefox

Tags: javascript, html, web, firefox

The following code allows type 6 digits in year. Using chrome and Edge with max propertie it goes correctly, but using firefox we can type 6 digits. Does anyone know how to fix this behaviour on firefox?

```
<input
  type="date"
  max="9999-12-31"
/>
```

[image: Image showing the behaviour using firefox]

Comment: The border of the input gets red though, which indicates there is an input error. You can check the date on form submit using javascript and inform the user with an alert for example.

Comment: If it is an issue specific to Firefox, it might be useful to specify the version you are targeting / using for tests.

Comment: I'm using Mozilla Firefox version 81.0.1 (64-bits)